# How to expose derived class function in boost python

Tags: c++, abstract-class, boost-python, derived-class

I would like to implement the expose module in derived class (.h or .cpp file). its work fine, when I exposed this in main in one BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE but when I exposed differently in abstract and derived class its get error **one or more multiply defined symbols errors.**  the example code is as follows.

```
 **Base.h**

   class Base
     {
       public:
       virtual void Set(const std::vector<std::string>& AllParameters) = 0;
      };

     struct BaseWrap : Base, wrapper<Base>
     {
        void Set(const std::vector<std::string>& AllParameters)
           {
             this->get_override("Set")(AllParameters);

           }

      **Base.cpp**

        BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Example)
          {
            class_<Basewrapper , boost::noncopyable> ("Base")
              .def("Set",pure_virtual(&Base::Set))
               ;
          }

       **Derived.h**

        class Derived : public Base
                 {
                  public:
                     int test(int a, int b);

                 };
             BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Example)
            {
                 class_<Derived , boost::noncopyable> ("Derived")
                   .def("test",&Derived ::test)
               ;
          }

        **Derived.cpp**


        void Derived:: test(int a , int b)

         { 
           return a+b; 

           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/module.html) macro defines a function with identifiers based on the provided argument.  Hence, defining the `Example` module in both `Base.cpp` and `Derived.h` violates the [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) when linking them into the same library.  To resolve this, consider splitting the function bodies that export each individual class into their own functions (i.e. `export_base()` and `export_derived()`), and have a single file (`example.cpp`) that defines `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` with a body that invokes the other export functions.  This technique can be seen [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/techniques.html#python.reducing_compiling_time).